# Azure - Detect region of virtual machine on virtual machine

Tags: azure

I want to deploy a scale set in two different regions on Azure from an custom virtual machine image. I've worked out how to do that, but I would like to switch configuration information depending on the region that the scale set is deployed. How can I detect the region of a virtual machine from that virtual machine?

The virtual machine is running CentOS.

Comment: where exactly must this happen?

Comment: On the virtual machine. I want a configuration file updated based on the region. The configuration file gets updated just before the web server starts up.

Comment: how do you configure it? with azure native capabilities or?

Comment: it's configured with a custom script in /etc

Comment: Perhaps this could be done with the Azure CLI and the `az vm list` command which returns a location for each VM.  Might not be advisable to run this from the actual VM though for the sake of obtaining a single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice easy way to do this, use the metadata service inside the VM. You can run this command from inside the VM (URL is the same for all VMs)

```
curl -H Metadata:true http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-03-01
```

and it will return a json object with data about the VM, including the region:

```
{
  "compute": {
    "location": "westus",
    "name": "avset2",
    "offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "placementGroupId": "",
    "platformFaultDomain": "1",
    "platformUpdateDomain": "1",
    "publisher": "Canonical",
    "resourceGroupName": "myrg",
    "sku": "16.04-LTS",
    "subscriptionId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "tags": "",
    "version": "16.04.201708030",
    "vmId": "13f56399-bd52-4150-9748-7190aae1ff21",
    "vmScaleSetName": "",
    "vmSize": "Standard_D1",
    "zone": "1"
  },
  "network": {
    "interface": [
      {
        "ipv4": {
          "ipAddress": [
            {
              "privateIpAddress": "10.1.2.5",
              "publicIpAddress": "X.X.X.X"
            }
          ],
          "subnet": [
            {
              "address": "10.1.2.0",
              "prefix": "24"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ipv6": {
          "ipAddress": []
        },
        "macAddress": "000D3A36DDED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the response: { "error": "Bad request. Required metadata header not specified" }

Comment: Upon googling based on your answer, this command came up and worked: curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01"

Answer (score 2):

Use *jq* to get only the region name

```
curl -s -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute?api-version=2021-02-01" | jq '.location'
```